# How to make if chains

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a game for my assignment in AS3.0 and this isn't working.
All the variables and buttons are defined, I get no error but it just dose not function : 

frame 2 layer 1

```
function CheckScene():void
{
    P_HP = 5
    E_HP = 1
    A_D = 1

    if(P_HP == 5)
        if(E_HP == 2)
            if(A_D == 1)
                q = 1

    if(P_HP == 5)
        if(E_HP == 1)
            if(A_D == 1)
                q = 2
        }
```

frame 2 layer 2

```
stop();

but.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndStop(5);
}
```

frame 3 layer 2

```
button_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2);

function fl_ClickToGoToAndStopAtFrame_2(event:MouseEvent):void
{
if(q == 1)
    gotoAndStop(5)
if(q == 2)
    gotoAndStop(4)
}
```

Basically it goes to frame 4 if it works, or  5 if it doesn't. The if chain isn't working. I have no clue how to do this because this sort of thing works in excel (for checking multiple variables before execution).

Comment: becus as uses java?

Comment: There is zero java source code in your examples. And in general, the Java answer is: you don't. You **avoid** lengthy if/else/switch constructs. They are hard to read, maintain, and not at all "good OO". In good OO you use **polymorphism**. Instead of asking some object for something and then calling methods, you carefully create objects that implement the same interface in different ways and just call methods on them. Watch https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79 esp. video 2.

Comment: "*as uses java*" is just wrong. There are compilers for actionscript written in java, but this doesn't make this a java question.  And actionscript itself has nothing to do with java. It's influenced by (or a dialect if you will) of ecmascript, which java**script** implements. Which despite also having "java" in its name, has nothing to do with java. Other than that, the object oriented principles of @GhostCat still apply. Java tag removed.

Comment: didn't know that thought AS used java. proplem with only knowing of the egsistents of AS 8 weeks ago gwtting tought it and then having to mack an education applacation

Answer (score 0):

See comments for help and explanation:

```
//use naming conventions : methods start with lower-case.
//fix method signature
private void  checkScene()
{
    //declare all variables
    //use naming conventions : variables start with lower-case.
    int p_HP = 5;  // ; at the end of every statement
    int e_HP = 1;
    int a_D = 1;
    int q = 0;

    if(p_HP == 5) {
        if(e_HP == 2) {
            if(a_D == 1) {
                q = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    //you could use an equivalent and shorter format:
    //if( p_HP==5 && e_HP==2 && a_D==1)  q=1; 

    if(p_HP == 5) {
        if(e_HP == 1) {
            if(a_D == 1) {
                q = 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //you could use an equivalent and shorter format:
    // if( p_HP==5 && e_HP==1 && a_D==1)  q=2; 

    //add printout to check the result
    System.out.println("q is "+q);
}
```

For future questions pleas post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)